# UserError.Throw with non-default backing field naming convention

Tags: reactiveui

I'm having trouble understanding what I'm doing wrong with the `UserError` class.

This is the code inside my ViewModel:

```
this.CheckForUpdateCmd = new ReactiveAsyncCommand(Observable.Return(true));

UserError.RegisterHandler(
    uerror =>    
    {
        logger.Error(uerror.ErrorMessage, uerror.InnerException);
        if (dlgService.ShowMessageBox(  
            this, 
            uerror.ErrorMessage, 
            ClientStrings.AboutVM_ErrorCheckUpdates, 
            MessageBoxButton.YesNo, 
            MessageBoxImage.Warning) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            return Observable.
                Return(RecoveryOptionResult.RetryOperation);
        }
        return Observable.  
            Return(RecoveryOptionResult.FailOperation);
    });

this.
        CheckForUpdateCmd.
        ThrownExceptions.
        SelectMany(ex => 
            UserError.Throw(
                ClientStrings.AboutVM_ErrorCheckUpdates, 
                ex)).
        Subscribe(
            recoverOption =>
            {
                if (recoverOption == RecoveryOptionResult.RetryOperation)
                {
                   this.CheckForUpdateCmd.Execute(null);
                }
            });

((ReactiveAsyncCommand)this.CheckForUpdateCmd).
    RegisterAsyncAction(_ =>
        { 
            throw new Exception("TESTING 123"); 
        });
```

After the exception is thrown inside the async action, it is correctly propagated to my `Usererror.Throw` inside the `SelectMany`. Inside the Throw method, RxUI throws an ArgumentException with: "You must declare a backing field for this property named: recoveryOptions"

I've investigated this and the UserError class has a `_RecoveryOptions` that is being set from the UserError itself. However, I'm throwing a wrench into the whole process with this inside my App's OnStartup event handler:

`RxApp.GetFieldNameForPropertyNameFunc = prop => prop.Length == 1 ? prop.ToLower() : char.ToLower(prop[0]) + prop.Substring(1);`

Basically, I want my backing fields to start with a lower-case letter, not underscore/upper. So far, RxUI has honored this until I tried to use UserError. Am I missing a step or is this a bug in RxUI?

This is for Reactive UI 3.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [old bug in ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/commit/cc070ff5bcda330d8b30a11e9051b954e71ca5b9) that has been fixed long ago - either upgrade to ReactiveUI 4.x, or copy [Errors.cs](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI.Xaml/Errors.cs) into your project and use that

Comment: Thanks for the info on this, Paul. And thanks for ReactiveUI!